# How to get the index of the current iterator item in a loop?

Tags: python, iterator

How to obtain the index of the current item of a Python [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-iterator) in a loop?

For example when using regular expression `finditer` function which returns an iterator, how you can access the index of the iterator in a loop.

```
for item in re.finditer(pattern, text):
    # How to obtain the index of the "item"
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Iterators were not designed to be indexed (remember that they produce their items lazily).

Instead, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to number the items as they are produced:

```
for index, match in enumerate(it):
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> it = (x for x in range(10, 20))
>>> for index, item in enumerate(it):
...     print(index, item)
...
0 10
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
5 15
6 16
7 17
8 18
9 19
>>>
```

Note that you can also specify a number to start the counting at:

```
>>> it = (x for x in range(10, 20))
>>> for index, item in enumerate(it, 1):  # Start counting at 1 instead of 0
...     print(index, item)
...
1 10
2 11
3 12
4 13
5 14
6 15
7 16
8 17
9 18
10 19
>>>
```